# Consumer commiting offsets but not getting listed through /v2/kafka/(cluster)/consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

I set up a burrow install and pointed to my Kafka server.(1 Broker and 1 zookeeper).When I call /v2/kafka/kafka1/consumer , I get the response, no 
consumers.

i.e `{"error": false,"message": "consumer list returned","consumers": [],"request": {"url": "/v2/kafka/local/consumer/","host": "", "cluster": "local","group": "","topic": ""}}`

My burrow.cfg is shown as

```
        [general]
        logdir=burrowlogs
        logconfig=config/logging.cfg
        pidfile=burrow.pid
        client-id=burrow-lagchecker
        group-blacklist=^(console-consumer-|python-kafka-consumer-).*$

        [zookeeper]
        hostname=
        port=2181
        timeout=6
        lock-path=/burrow/notifier

        [kafka "local"]
        broker=
        broker-port=9092
        zookeeper=
        zookeeper-port=2181
        zookeeper-path=/
        offsets-topic=__consumer_offsets

        [storm "local"]
        #zookeeper=zkhost01.example.com
        #zookeeper=zkhost02.example.com
        #zookeeper=zkhost03.example.com
        #zookeeper-port=2181
        #zookeeper-path=/kafka-cluster/stormconsumers

        [tickers]
        broker-offsets=60

        [lagcheck]
        intervals=10
        expire-group=604800

        [httpserver]
        server=on
        port=8080

        [smtp]
        server=mailserver.example.com
        port=25
        from=burrow-noreply@example.com
        template=config/default-email.tmpl

        [email "bofh@example.com"]
        group=local,critical-consumer-group
        group=local,other-consumer-group
        interval=60

        [httpnotifier]
        url=http://notification.server.example.com:9000/v1/alert
        interval=60
        extra=app=burrow
        extra=tier=STG
        template-post=config/default-http-post.tmpl
        template-delete=config/default-http-delete.tmpl
        timeout=5
        keepalive=30

        My burrow.out is

        Started Burrow at June 30, 2016 at 3:07pm (UTC)
        2016/06/30 15:10:27 http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls
        2016/06/30 15:10:29 http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls
        2016/06/30 15:10:38 http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls
        2016/06/30 15:10:39 http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls
        2016/06/30 15:10:40 http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls
        2016/06/30 15:10:41 http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls
        2016/06/30 15:10:42 http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls
        2016/06/30 15:10:44 http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls
        2016/06/30 15:10:45 http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls
        2016/06/30 15:10:45 http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls
        2016/06/30 15:10:47 http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls
```

I am using Kafka version 0.10.0.

My offset.storage = kafka.

I know that cluster is connected to a consumer and in processing messages. All other endpoints, not at the consumer level, appear to work fine.

Comment: Have you found a solution? Are you using the old consumer api? I had the same problem and I switched to KafkaConsumer and the consumer related endpoints in burrow started to display data.

Comment: Hi @lotusdragon I am new to kafka can you tell me what is kafkaConsumer?

Comment: Look at the new consumer api: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#consumerapi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved. Just need to add zookeeper-offset = true in my burrow.cfg this will solve the problem if you are storing the offset details of Kafka topics in zookeeper.